# VBA When attempting to export an excel sheet with ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat I get RunTime Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I simply want to unhide a sheet that contains a report then export that sheet as a pdf then hide it once again and go back to another sheet, however when running this code I receive a "RunTime Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Sub Print_To_PDF()


Sheets("Report").Visible = True
Sheets("Report").Select

Dim pdfname As String

pdfname = Range("A1").Value


ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Sheets("Report").Visible = False
Sheets("Summary").Select

End Sub
```

It works sometimes and even on other computers not sure why I am getting this error. Can someone please help.

Comment: What does `Debug.print pdfname` output in the Immediate Window? Likely shouldn't be selecting here or using `ActiveSheet` explicitly or implicitly: `pdfname = Sheets("Report").Range("A1").Value`, `Sheets("Report").ExportAsFixedFormat...`

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, debug print simply prints the value in cell A1 to be used as the name of the pdf file. I tried ur suggestions by redefining pdfname as well as replacing ActiveSheet with Sheets("Report") but I am still receiving the same error, sigh.

Comment: Is your filename valid? Does it contain any illegal characters?

Comment: No no illegal characters, this same code works on other computers not seeing why it isn't working on mine.

Comment: Do you have write permission for the destination folder?

Comment: Im not sure, how would i determine the destination folder from this code?

Comment: Maybe you should specify the full path when saving and not just the filename then?

Comment: Yes by specifying the path it is now working thanks so much !

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```vb
Sub Print_To_PDF()
    
    Dim pdfname As String

    pdfname = Range("A1").Value 'ideally specify a worksheet here!
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
        .Visible = True
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
           Filename:=pdfname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
           IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
           OpenAfterPublish:=True
        .Visible = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response however I am still getting RunTime Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: If you're getting an error, it's useful to tell us which specific line the error occurs on.  If you're not supplying the full path and filename in A1, then try doing that.

Comment: Yes by specifying the full path it is now working thank you !

Answer (score 0):

As best practice in the Excel object library (VBA or any COM interfacing code), always qualify objects such as Workbooks, Worksheets, Ranges, QueryTables, PivotTables, and other objects to the parent context. See this canonical post, [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for readability, maintainability, and reliability.

Therefore, consider explicitly qualifying each object or use a `With...End With` block. Additionally, consider proper error handling which can provide further information for your debugging needs.

```vb
Sub Print_To_PDF()
On Error Goto ErrHandle:
    Dim pdfname As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report")
        .Visible = True
        pdfname = .Range("A1").Value

        .ExportAsFixedFormat _
             Type:=xlTypePDF, _
             Filename:=pdfname, _
             Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
             IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
             IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
             OpenAfterPublish:=True

        .Visible = False
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Select

ExitHandle:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    Msgbox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response however I am still getting RunTime Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error in the msg box